# Is there a JavaScript library to validate xml against RELAX NG schema

Tags: javascript, xml, validation, relaxng

Is there a JavaScript library to validate xml against RELAX NG schema? I tried [jsrelaxngvalidator](http://code.google.com/p/jsrelaxngvalidator/) but it is slow and doesn't work for large schemas. Are there any other JavaScript RELAX NG schema validators?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out https://github.com/simonster/csl-validator.js (live at http://simonster.github.com/csl-validator.js/ ). It's a JavaScript validator for the Citation Style Language (CSL) RELAX NG Compact schema (see citationstyles.org), built onto the RNV validator (written in C) via emscripten.